# CURL web page that has captcha?

Tags: php, session, curl, cookies, captcha

I am trying to cURL a webpage which has captcha then I am getting the image and show it to user then submit but I am getting session expired error. not even incorrect captcha error.

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0)     Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $matches);
$cookies = array();
foreach($matches[1] as $item) {
parse_str($item, $cookie);
$cookies = array_merge($cookies, $cookie);
}
```

Then if code is submitted;

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo); 
foreach($cookies as $key => $val) {
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $key.'='.$cookie);
}
```

I am trying almost everything on the internet but I couldn't manage anything.

Comment: In your foreach $cookies loop, each subsequent call will overwrite the cookie you set in the last iteration, so ultimately you are sending one cookie value.  curl can handle cookies for you so it's better to let it handle it.

Comment: Actually there is only one cookie 

url FALSE / FALSE 0 phpSess_RANDOM RANDOM2

Comment: It's hard to see what's going on because the code is incomplete.  In the second example, where does `$cookies` come from?  Unless you store them somewhere, this is probably a different cookie than the first request.

Comment: Instead of trying to do the cookies yourself, use the `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` options so that `curl` will do it automatically.

Comment: That also gives me session expired